# Why my website hosted on aws refuses to connect?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a node app which runs on localhost perfectly, I hosted it on AWS ec2 instance on port 80 and it worked fine too, after 7 days of inactivity when I searched public IP address of my ec2 instance(on any browser), it says <public_ipv4> refused to connect.

Here are a few things I did for troubleshooting which I read from AWS forums but not getting any luck:

1. deleted the node_modules/ directory and reinstalled using npm
   install command
2. Have correctly allowed HTTP traffic on port 80 inside inbound rules of security groups for that instance(i have only one instance running)
3. Ran netstat -nplt | grep 80 , which gave me output :

   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
4. I have added a script in package.json file, through which app.js file will run

In my app.js file i am listening to port 80:

```
app.listen(80, async  function(){
  console.log("server has started");
})
```

What else am I missing?

Screenshot of inbound rules :[image]

Comment: reproduce the following steps restart your ec2 instance, note down its public IP,try connecting it, if you cant, ssh into your instance heck whether node server is running or not and then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you have allowed only IP v6 address on Inbound traffic of Security Groups..

Not added allow permission for IPv4 address..

Add below rule

```
HTTP tcp 0.0.0.0/0  80
```

if you have added both rule ( IPV4 and IPV6) then

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :80
```

should show below both lines..

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

but in your case it showing only tcp6

Comment: so how do i check and add permission for ipv4 address.  if you are talking about inbound rules , i have allowed ipv4 too

Comment: how do i add this rule : HTTP tcp 0.0.0.0/0  80 ? which linux command is to be used

Comment: @RitishGupta you just need to add in SecurityGroup inbound rules

Comment: yes, I have did that, I can share the screenshot if you want, in my inbound rules it shows this:

Comment: HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
HTTP
TCP
80
::/0

Comment: 7 , i am also sharing the screenshot

Comment: are you sure that , you using correct security group .. may be you are modifying different security group?

Comment: or may be denied ipv4 traffic in NACL rules.

Comment: inside security groups coulmn of my instance "launch-wizard-1" is written and i am modifying that security group only. And can you elaborate about denied ipv4 traffic in nacl rules

Comment: sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :80  what output it showing now

Comment: same output as before: tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN

Answer (score 2):

See if the steps below helps.

1. Did you stop your ec2 instance start and it again if you did it would have changed your public ip if that is case use the new public ip.
2. Check your security groups attached to the ec2 instance if it allows in bound traffic on port 80.
   [image]
3. If the first step does not work connect to your ec2 instance and run a curl command to see if your app is running.

Comment: yes i did stopped the instance and also configured the inbound rules again for that instance.

Comment: and how do i use curl command to check app status?

Comment: when in ec2 shell try curl localhost if this does not work that means it's a problem with your app and not with your setup. Also make sure you are using the latest public ip as it would have changed.

Comment: See the image you should have an inbound rule as shown.

Comment: curl localhost gave me an html with title = "Test Page for the Apache HTTP Server"

Comment: yes , i have correctly added inbound rules according to the image you have shared, and yes i am using the new(changed) public ip , and also curl command is giving me html. What else could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my app.js file i have used port 80 :

```
app.listen(80, async  function(){
  console.log("server has started");
})
```

but when i changed port number to 3000 in app.listen , it worked , i dont't know how did this happen though.
There was no issue with security groups.